# Spring batch jobs from Web ui?

Tags: java, spring-batch

Has anyone worked or has any experience with executing spring batch jobs from web UI. Currently I have written few jobs for data-copy from CSV to DB table, it runs fine from command prompt and in a JUnit test.  But now these jobs have to be executed through web, JSF is being used as the front controller framework. Any suggestions about the best practices in this case would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean you just want to trigger batch job from UI (May be on some button click) or you want to schedule it from UI ?

Comment: Worked fine for me. Do you use Spring Batch Admin?http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch-admin/getting-started.html

Comment: hello aviad, did you also customize you spring batch admin?

Comment: Tarun: please accept some answers so that people will be more likely to help you.

Answer (score 5):

Spring Batch Admin is a deployable web frontend for your Spring Batch jobs. If all you want is a simple UI instead of a shell script for Administrators, take this approach:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch-admin/getting-started.html

If you're looking for a way to integrate the job trigger mechanism with your existing application, look at this implementation using Spring's JobLauncher which can be invoked from Controller/Servlet:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureJob.html#runningJobsFromWebContainer